# Birt changing by script the number format in one column table

Tags: javascript, birt

In a Birt report I'd like to change the number format depending on the data values.

I tried this in `onRender` of the table's script to test how changing format programmaticaly :

```
var df = new Packages.java.text.DecimalFormat("#,###.000000");
df.format(row["tensionEcm1"]);
```

There is no effect on the column display. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`df.format` is a function that returns the formatted value as a string.
You are calling this function, but you throw away the result!

What you should do:
Take your JS as is, but remove the final semicolon `;`, and use this as an expression for a dynamic text item (with content type "Plain").